# Can't make URL requests to resources through urllib.request

Tags: python, urllib, urllib2

I followed the instructions to make a URL request here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

But hasn't been able to make the request successful.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

URL = 'http://zhishi.me/api/entity/'
term_str = '瓦朗谢讷足球俱乐部'
encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(URL + term_str)
with urllib.request.urlopen(encoded_url) as response:
   html = response.read()
   html = html.decode('utf-8')
   print(html)
```

This generates the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/nlp/baike/downloader/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen(encoded_url) as response:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 511, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 355, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 384, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'http%3A%2F%2Fzhishi.me%2Fapi%2Fentity%2F%E7%93%A6%E6%9C%97%E8%B0%A2%E8%AE%B7%E8%B6%B3%E7%90%83%E4%BF%B1%E4%B9%90%E9%83%A8'
```

Comment: The first problem is URL: `urlopen(urllib.parse.urljoin(URL, term_str))`

Comment: I tried, but that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to correct it:

```
base_url = 'http://zhishi.me/api/entity/'
para = urllib.parse.quote('瓦朗谢讷足球俱乐部')
url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url,para)

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   html = response.read()
   html = html.decode('utf-8')
   print(html)
```